# Bucket files still saved locally when using dev_appserver and --support_datastore_emulator=false

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, bucket, dev-appserver

I'm running a local instance of a PHP app-engine project, I have got some buckets setup in GCP specifically for the local dev version, however instead of the data that I write to the bucket appearing online, they are being saved locally into the dev_appserver Datastore. I can see the files in the local admin interface (localhost:8000) under Datastore.

This is an issue as the application I'm developing has a companion app which needs to also access the bucket files.

The

```
--support_datastore_emulator=[true|false]
```

flag is documented under

```
dev_appserver.py -h
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect when using =false.

So my question is: How do I stop the dev_appserver from using the local Datastore and make it use the 'real' buckets on the web?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **--default_gcs_bucket_name** flag documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#using_the_client_library_with_the_development_app_server) to establish the default GCS bucket to use:

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml --default_gcs_bucket_name gs://BUCKET-NAME
```

Comment: Great! thanks. I'll try this tonight. Would this parameter still apply/work when using multiple buckets?

Comment: Adding the --default_gcs_bucket_name seems to enable the datastore emulator locally, I also tried adding the --support_datastore_emulator=false to no avail. When adding the --default_gcs_bucket_name, dev_appserver seems to convert from the sqlite datastore to the emulator datastore .db. But both are still local. If it helps, my app accesses the buckets through gs://[bucket-name] but files and folders are not being created in the cloud.